# Almost a curse?

Tags: riddle, word, english

What am I?

> My last three letters serve to clarify.
> My first four letters are where famous people speak.
> Dropping all consonants, I am almost a curse.

The solution is a single English word and, once found, will leave no doubt that it is the intended one.

**Hint**

> The solution explains how the riddle must be modified to yield the solution.

Comment: I thought line 2 was "film" but I can't get anywhere with it. Cool puzzle.

Comment: Curse as in magical, or curse as in "bad word"? (tbh I can't think of any which are primarily vowels regardless)

Comment: I guess it could be "play" instead of "film" but I still get stuck.

Comment: @Raystafarian I was thinking along the lines of "dais" or "hall", I hadn't considered that direction!

Comment: I went straight to dais as well, but I can't imagine a word with that as the first four letters. Could go film, play, maybe even show

Comment: @question_asker - I was thinking of dais as well, and was thinking of daisy (or daisychain) as the complete word.  Couldn't go anywhere from there though.

Comment: 'curse' can simply mean a really unforunate situation.

Comment: @pew is there a reason why you put the last three letters before the first for in the riddle?

Comment: @pew Are you here? I m considering to offer bounty on this question.

Comment: @manshu: I am here, and none of the answers thus far is the intended one.

Comment: are you sure that you will be monitoring incoming answers in future coz you replied after a month..?

Comment: 2nd one could be a synonym of twitter and 3rd one could be synonym of curse which is missing a letter or two. Could not find any answer.

Comment: @Tanuj Can you think of any curse in your regional language which fits here?

Comment: I can not figure this out for the life of me. I was trying to find a way to use "y", but I got nothing. Then I tried thinking laterally (words that are similar to the word "a curse"), but I was just spinning my tires. The best I can come up with is "foreshow", but that's a stretch. (OH EEE OH!! being the "curse"). bah.

Comment: @manshu, no. This might help http://www.wordfind.com/scrabble-vowel-words/

Comment: It just occurred to me, what if "dropping all consonants" is taken to mean using only consonants? I can think of many "almost curses" using just consonants. E.G. "fck".

Comment: @richardroe yeah my assumption is that they mixed up vowels and consonants but I want to give them the benefit of the doubt

Comment: @manshu: Still here :) I log in rarely, but I definitely will keep coming back.

Comment: @pew You'll give us the answer one day, right?

Comment: @pew it hasn't been solved? If not I came up with a persons name that fits the criteria but you said word.

Comment: @pew how about a hint?

Comment: Alright, here is a **hint** (in ROT13): Gur fbyhgvba rkcynvaf ubj gur evqqyr zhfg or zbqvsvrq gb lvryq gur fbyhgvba.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given the hint, I guess the answer is

> SHIFTED.

The gimmick is that:

> The predicate of each sentence needs to be **shifted** cyclically upward once, yielding the actual riddle:
>  My last three letters **are where famous people speak.**
>  My first four letters, **I am almost a curse.**
>  Dropping all consonants **serve to clarify.**

The answer fits this riddle because:

> The last three letter: TED= [A TED Talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TED_(conference)).
>  My first four letters: SHIF ~ ___T.
>  Dropping all consonants: IE=[i.e., id est](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/id_est), used to clarify.

Comment: Very nice! This one has been bugging me on and off for a while, and this answer makes sense.

Answer (score 13):

Is it:

> Daisies

Because:

> I.e.'s are an example of something, used for clarification. 
>  Dais is a platform on which people speak. 
>  And I know this is a stretch but a lowercase a can look like a d without the top vertical line so the vowels are close to reading diie. 
>  Alternative pointed out by Hugh is aïe is French for "dang."

Worth a shot.

Comment: I like this one! +1 but I don't know if it is correct or not. Will wait for other answers and a possible comment from the OP before I give the bounty.

Comment: Sorry, don't know how I missed seeing your post. For the curse part, see here: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/a%C3%AFe I deleted my post which had basically the same answer.

Comment: @HughMeyers no biggie. I got you by 12 hours but your explanation to the last part is likely a little better. ;)

Comment: @Pew never said whether or not you were right, but half the bounty will go to you in a couple hours anyway, so you may as well have the whole thing. Besides, your answer looks good to me!

Comment: I agree with @richardroe, this one deserves it whether or not it's the intended answer

Comment: Wow. This answer actually contains a part of the intended solution! See also the hint given as a comment above.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is

> Show

My last three letters serve to clarify.

> last three letters are 'how' which is asked when we need clarification

My first four letters are where famous people speak.

> famous people speak at different shows.

Dropping all consonants, I am almost a curse.

> When dropped all consonents then has some pronouncing similarity with 'whore'. Or as APrough commented "You also go "Oh, #$%^@" (insert your own favorite curse word). So, technically it is almost a curse."

Comment: Dropping all consonants, 'show' becomes 'o'...

Comment: @PatrickN fixed

Comment: You also go "Oh, #$%^@" (insert your own favorite curse word).  So, technically it is almost a curse...

Comment: To avoid any unnecessary speculation, I just want to make explicit that this is not the intended solution ("o" is not really "almost a curse").

Comment: @pew are semi-vowels also counted as consonents here?

Comment: @manshu If you're talking about Y, it is not a semi-vowel -- it is either a consonant or a vowel, depending on context.  Thus if all consonants are dropped, I imagine Y would be dropped if it were a consonant in the context of that word, and would not be dropped if it were a vowel in the context of that word.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I imagine he was talking about W, since that's a semi-vowel and appears in his word

Answer (score 7):

My guess is:

> Discourage

My last three letters serve to clarify.

> With age usually comes clarification on most things due to gained experiences and knowledge.

My first four letters are where famous people speak.

> Famous people speak in movies which are often held on a disc (DVD, Blue-ray, etc.).

Dropping all consonants, I am almost a curse.

> Removing all consonants gives: i, o, u, a and e or another way to look at it: I O U A&E. This can be seen as 'I owe you A&E' (the British, Irish, New Zealand, and Hong Kong term for a hospital's emergency department) which is **almost** an offensive word or phrase used to express anger or annoyance (a definition of curse). Personally, I would interpret this phrase as someone telling me they want to beat me up/send me to A&E.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE! Congratulations on a good first answer.

Comment: @pew is this right? It looks good to me.

Answer (score 6):

You are..

> Linear

My logic:

> - Famous people speak in lines(in movies)
>  - Ear, in which you speak to clarify 
>  - The curse part is still bugging me, perhaps that is the curse of it all?

Comment: Why the down vote? U haven't broken any rules and the guess is in line with the riddle? Down voting on riddles will make me hesitant to try guessing in the future

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but it could be that you don't have the 3rd part completely answered yet?  But I do agree with you on downvotes without explanation.  It is baffling...

Comment: I upvoted to make it even as I too don't understand, I assume you must be wrong as it hasn't been accepted but that's not a reason to downvote

Comment: I've seen a lot of incomplete answers be filled out in the comments.  There is nothing wrong with saying *This fulfills 2/3 requirements, can anyone think of how it could satisfy the third.*  Downvoter be warned: yer not wanted around these parts.

Comment: I think that the reason of the downvote is covered in [my question on meta site](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/what-to-keep-in-mind-while-answering-puzzle?cb=1)

Comment: To avoid any unnecessary speculation, I just want to make explicit that this is not the intended solution (the third part doesn't really match, does it?).

Comment: And to avoid more speculation, I did not and will never downvote any honest attempt at a solution.

Comment: @pew hehe, the third part sorta matches but only in a long shot. There are some sneaky riddles here which have actually done similar things. But I understand this is not the correct answer even tho the guess might be ok at best. And thank you for not downvoting, it's fun to guess but since they are all guesses they shouldn't be downvoted just because they're wrong (if they're horrible and no explanation to the guesses, sure) : )

Comment: The curse is clearly IKEA!!!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if any of these are the intended answer, but thought I'd throw a few more ideas out there for others to build on...

1. > **FACEMASK** (You **ASK** to clarify something. Famous people speak from their **FACE**. The vowels, **AEA** are valid hexadecimal values, and a hex is a type of curse)
2. > **PAGEANTRY** (You **TRY** something if you want to clarify if it works. Famous people speak via the **PAGE**. **AEA** as above) - also **tapestry** via similar logic for those who grew up in the VHS days, or **telemetry** if you abbreviate television as "tele"...
3. > **DISCOTHEQUE** (**QUE** can be used in spanish as a clarifying "What?". Movies containing famous people come on DVD **DISC**s. **IOEUE** is almost IOU (I owe you), which could be seen as a curse...)

Comment: Discotheque. I like that. Really creative. ^vote

Comment: I like th(is|ese) answer[s] a lot

Answer (score 3):

My answer is:

> Boombox

My last three letters serve to clarify.

> e.g, drawing a box around an answer or perhaps ticking a box to clarify a position.

My first four letters are where famous people speak.

> A boom is a large mike on the end of a stick usually used for actors or people being interviewed.

Dropping all consonants, I am almost a curse.

> 'ooo' is almost 'poo' (if you add an extra line)

Comment: I don't know that poo is a curse.

Answer (score 3):

My attempt at this!
The word is

> **Bookshelf**

My last three letters serve to clarify.

> **ELF**'s clarifying magic can be seen [here](http://www.elfcosmetics.com.au/products/e-l-f-essential-clarifying-pressed-powder#.VuevE_l97IU)

My first four letters are where famous people speak.

> **BOOK** is where famous people speak out their auto-biographies.

Dropping all consonants, I am almost a curse.

> **OOE** or Out Of Endurance is almost a curse if you're playing Dark age of Camelot, because if you don't have an endurance potion, you will die. [SEE HERE](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ooe)

Answer (score 3):

Could the word be

> Confix?

My last three letters serve to clarify.

> fix - to repair or correct, stabilize, direct.

My first four letters are where famous people speak.

> conf - short for conference.

Dropping all consonants, I am almost a curse.

> Oi! What's the big idea giving us a stumper like this!?

Answer (score 3):

What am I?

> Cipher

My last three letters serve to clarify.

> her, is a pronoun - used to clarify referents, without using names.

My first four letters are where famous people speak.

> CIPH (Collège international de philosophie).  Yeah, famous people spoke there.  Lectured, taught, and thought as well, probably.  Yay for acronyms!

Dropping all consonants, I am almost a curse.

> ie, ie...  Fie! fie, a curse upon thee!  if only the vowels are 'almost' a curse means they need a little more.  The addition of 'F' makes a fine, traditional curse.

Hint

> The hint from the comments, "Gur fbyhgvba rkcynvaf ubj gur evqqyr zhfg or zbqvsvrq gb lvryq gur fbyhgvba" translates to "the solution explains how the riddle must be modified to yield the solution".
>
>  What must we do to the riddle to find the answer?  outthink it, puzzle through it, or cipher it - a word which means to encode, but also to solve problems!  As a bonus, it is also how the hint is found.

Answer (score 2):

My random guess:

> Wingspan

Because,

> A wing of a building is a place to make a speech.
>  A pan can serve to clarify *butter* by melting it. 
> Ai! as an exclamation isn't usually considered a curse but it's close.

I also considered

> Walleye

But I couldn't figure out how that would be a curse.

If this isn't it

> It might have to do with *letters* 
> oic: Oh, I see? 
> icy:I see why? 
> our:Oh, you are? 
> ucy: You see why?
>  I can't really figure out the other letters that might be with TV though.

Answer (score 2):

## Not an Answer - Just Some Thoughts

Almost a curse:

> It occurred to me that some people use "a-hole" as a curse. So "U A O" might be considered close to "You a-hole" depending on how you pronounce it. Possibly even "U A" might be considered almost a curse but that would not make me happy if it were the solution.
>
>
>  Another possibility for cursing could be "O I U" as in "Oi, you!" This is a British expression meaning basically "hey, you" but it is rather aggressive and might be considered almost a curse. "Oi" or "Oy" is also a Yiddish exclamation as in "Oy vey" or "oy gevalt" but it's really more dismay than cursing.

Clarifying:

> google "ion clarify". Lots of hits, so potentially anything ending in ion could qualify. Doesn't work at all with my "almost a curse" idea of course.

Where famous people speak

> might refer to politics. The Hill is a name for Washington DC. I couldn't go any further with this but are there other four letter names for places where politicians speak?
>  A quad is a place, but not particularly one where famous people speak.
>  The United Nations General Assembly UNGA is a place where famous people speak but "ungainly" doesn't fit with any other clues.

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> hall

My last three letters serve to clarify.

> "It's **all**right"

My first four letters are where famous people speak.

> hall

Dropping all consonants, I am almost a curse.

> h*e*ll

Comment: Dropping all consonants, "hall" becomes "a", not "hell" :)

Comment: @pew, damn, had a dumb moment and thought that consonants were voxels

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> Teles??

Because:

> '**Les'** in French would mean "the" a word which *specifies*;
>  '**Tele'** would mean television where famous people appear; 
> '**Ee'** is an [exclamatory word](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ee) in northern England. And coincidentally also a word to display [disbelief and surprise](https://youtu.be/wkQJddDQv5E) word in commonly used [Japanese](http://www.jref.com/articles/japanese-slang.210/) language