# (According to me.)

Tags: cipher, wordplay, knowledge

## Can you identify the six things below and determine the final answer?

**First thing**

> - My first three are the code for [a port airport in Malaysia](http://www.mapsofworld.com/international-airports/asia/malaysia.html).
> - Next you'll need one of the least-common Scrabble tiles.
> - Finally, don't look in nature for my last two, they were first made in Germany in 1984.

**Second thing**

> - My first three are broadcast by the USA, but not in the USA.
> - Next, you’ll find the original ObiWan.
> - My last two are where you want to be on a rainy day.

**Third thing**

> - All hail my first three in times of need!
> - My last five are what you had to do with a pen in [this recent Alconja puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43276/rejb%C3%84s-an-unfinished-flat-pack-puzzle).

**Fourth thing**

> - I begin with two neighbors who together can make a beetle.
> - My next two are a coin flip in ancient Rome.
> - My last two are a guy on a baseball team.  Or on an American football team.

**Fifth thing**

> - My first three can be found by taking the 5th, 2nd, and 7th of a well-known sequence.
> - Take half of that same sequence to get my last two.

**Sixth thing**

> - My first four are a bit bloody.
> - My last six are a place of peace and tranquility, or peril.

**Final thing**

> According to all of you (↑), I am `vyvjijljifvzzlrk`

---

**Hint for the third thing**

> Hail is used as a verb, but not in the sense of acclaim or glorification.
>  In the puzzle mentioned, we indeed had to do *something*, but "thin" is not the right verb for **_ _ _ _ K**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After solving the sixth thing, [Gareth proposed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45032/according-to-me/45041#45041) that ...

> ... the "things" are the names of transformations to which that transformation is applied.

This seems to be true. In particular, the first thing ...

> ... is **ATBASH** encoded with the [Atbash cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash): **ZGYZHS**
>
>  **ZGY** is the IATA code of Kuching Port Airport. The **Z** tile occurs only once in a Scrabble set and scores 10. **HS** is the chemical symbol of Hassium.

The second thing ...

> ... is **RAILFENCE** encoded with the [railfence cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher):
>
> ```
>     R       F       E
>       A   L   E   C
>         I       N
> ```
>
> Radio Free Europe or **RFE** is an US-govermnent funded broadcaster in Europe. **ALEC** Guinness played Obi-Wan Kenobi in the original Star Wars and when you are at home, or **IN**, you're dry in rainy weather.

The third thing ...

> ... is **BACKWARD** backward: **DRAWKCAB**.
>
>  You can hail a **CAB** and we had to **DRAW K**, i.e. follow a series of instructions to draw the letter K, in Alconja's puzzle. The clues to this thing are in backwards order, too, because they put the "cab" before the "draw K".
>
>  (This thing was solved by Gareth, with whom I agree that the cab clue should come last, so that the clues in order yield the whole word backwards.)

The fourth thing ...

> ... is **VOWELLESS** without vowels: **VWLLSS**.
>
>  Volkswagen or **VW** for short produced the Beetle. A coin toss is fifty-fifty or **LL** in Roman numbers. And **SS** could be a Shortstop in baseball or Strong Safety in American football.

The fifth thing ...

> ... is **ROT13** encoded with Rot13: **EBG13**.
>
>  The sequence in question isn't any numerical sequence, but the English alphabet, whose fifth, second and seventh elements are **E**, **B** and **G**. The alphabet as 26 letters, so half of it is **13**. (And it's quite embarrassing how long it took me to find this thing.)

The sixth thing ...

> ... was found by Gareth Mc Caughan. It is **REARRANGED** rearranged to **RARE GARDEN**.

The final answer:

> At first I thought that the answer was a word that would be subjected to all transformations and that the final result of these transformations would be `vyvjijljifvzzlrk`. That can't be true, because when working backwards from that word, the last step is a transposition, which doesn't change the contained letters, and the seond but last step is Rot13, which yields a word with i's and e's. That can't be the result of the fourth step, which is to strip all vowels.
>
>  The procedure is to start with `vyvjijljifvzzlrk` and apply all transformations to it:
>
>  Atbash → `ebeqrqoqrueaaoip`
>  Railfence → `errabqqquaopeoei`
>  Backward → `ieoepoauqqqbarre`
>  Vowelless → `pqqqbrr`
>  Rot13 → `cdddoee`
>  Rearranged → `decoded`

So the final answer is:

> According to all of you (↑), I am **DECODED**.

Comment: J not Z for your tile.  Looking good!

Comment: I've been staring into an alphabet soup for the last hours, I can't tell my Js from my Zs anymore ...

Comment: Ha. I contemplated IGPAYATINLAY too. (Perhaps we both looked at the Wikipedia list of classical ciphers page.)

Comment: I've vistited that list several times today, but I'm not sure whether I got to to Pig Latin from there or from elsewhere. I'm a bit out of ideas where to look and I'm not very fond of trying to fit keys to match various cipher names to the things.

Comment: "Finally the transformations don't have to be ciphers at all." Exactly! I will say that neither part of the third thing has been correctly solved yet, and the middle part of the fourth thing has not been correctly solved yet either.

Comment: Awesome. I'll add a couple hints for the remaining one.

Comment: Third thing, of course (now that we have Dan's recent hints) is CAB + DRAWK, though surely they should be in the other order, making BACKWARD.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Ah, of course! I seem to have suspected that the third thing was a reversal, because I used it as placeholder in the final answer, but couldn't see how it worked.

Comment: @MOehm I think you probably did enough research along these lines of what's possible that you can post a sequel at some point!

Comment: I've certainly widened my knowledge of classical ciphers by exploring too many dead ends. Great puzzle and great misdirections in the clues. This was tough, although in hindsight it shouldn't have been. I also liked that you didn't give hints too readily when there was only slow process.

Comment: MOehm and @GarethMcCaughan: By the by, this was partially inspired by the hint (in comments) for [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25248/almost-a-curse) as-yet-unsolved puzzle.  I feel like there might be a good answer for that one, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 8):

I bet the sixth is

> RARE GARDEN which is an anagram of REARRANGED. (Note that GARDEN is an anagram of DANGER.)

Perhaps each of the six things is

> a word describing a means of transformation, transformed by that means. So e.g. one might be CAESAR with each letter moved forwards three places: FDHVDU. Alas, none of our things seems to be that, nor does it look as if any of them is likely to start with any shift of CAE. (If our Malaysian airport is JHB and our Scrabble letter is J, a shift of 2 yields KICK IT; if JHB and Z, a shift of 19 yields CAUSAL; I think these are coincidences. I haven't explored Caesar shifts of anything else.) ... Dan's recent edit indicates that actually the airport probably isn't JHB.

In comments MOehm finds that

> if we take the Malaysian airport to be ZGY and the Scrabble letter to be Z, we get ATBASH atbashed, which seems like confirmation for this theory.

A few other notes that haven't led me anywhere much so far:

> The Malaysian port airports seem to be: ZJT ZMK ZJR ZJB ZGY ZLW ZWR. Presumably the last two letters of #2 are IN. I agree that #3 seems to be SOSTHINK. Perhaps with a bit of stretching the Roman coin flip in #4 could be ALEA (CAPUT AUT NAVIA seems too long). Or maybe it's a Roman coin name backwards; SA, perhaps. The "final thing" has a lot of structure to it; it looks as if the letters come in pairs, suggesting maaaybe some sort of 5x5 grid, but then it's surprising that we have both I and J. Perhaps the grid is missing Q or Z. Or perhaps it works in a completely different way.

Comment: After you got the foot in the door with your first answer I've been thinking along similar lines, especially "things are word transformations the clues have been transformed with", but I haven't gotten anywhere, so thanks for posting your thoughts. If `vyvjijljifvzzlrk` is the answer transformed six times, one of the trafos is rearrangement and the other trafos are simple letter substitutions the answer could be a word with the same distribution of letters, eg "counterintuitive". (But that's a stretch; there are only so many one-to-one substitution ciphers.)

Comment: Yup, possible. But look at all the letters repeated with spacing 2 in that VYVJ thing -- surely that isn't just coincidence?

Comment: Ha! The airport is ZGY - thanks for the updated list! - and the Scrabble letter is Z, which gives ATBASH. Maybe it's time to reverse-engineer some common ciphers.

Comment: Oooo, you clever clever person.

Comment: (And it looks like we have confirmation for the X-applied-to-"X" theory. Too bad none of the things appears to be '"QUINED"quined',)

Comment: ... in which case, you may well be absolutely right about VYVJ... and maybe the repeating patterns are just because Dan decided to arrange the letters that way for extra confusion.

Comment: Not so much clever as lucky in trying out some things. I've tried out more, but without success so far. There isn't any key (that I can see), so I've focussed on ciphers without keys. Dvorak encoding yields EKRPAT; Bifid with the standard square yields BGBQT, Playfair with standard square LMDVLFGT. I can't fit Caesar or Rot X to the clues.

Comment: But, but! The dry place is indeed IN, the original Obi-Wan is, of course, ALEC and the American radio outside America is neither VOA nor AFN, but Radio Free Europe: RAILFENCE encoded with itself.

Answer (score 2):

The first seems to be

> KUL(J/X/Q/Z)HS (Kuala Lumpur)(Scrabble)(Hassium) KUL could also be any of PEN,BKI,KCH,JHB,LGK

I think the third is

> SOSTHINK(S.O.S.)(Thin K)

The fourth may be

> VW(NAC?)SS(Volkswagon)(navia aut caput?)(Shortstop/Strong Safety)

I notice that none of these appear to be actual words, I wonder if I'm way off target, or if the cipher applies to more than the Final Thing.

Comment: I'm unsure whether we are looking for real words as well

Answer (score 0):

Second thing:

> VOA AG ???

Explanations:

> Voice of America is a US propaganda radio broadcast outside of the US. The original Obiwan Kenobee in Star Wars IV-VI was played by Alec Guinness.

Comment: Please can you [edit] this answer to include more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The fourth seems to be

> **VWCNSS** - (Will be 6 characters if this is wrong)

Because

> VW = VolksWagon
>  CN = Capita vel Navia
>  SS = Short Stop
>
>  Take the first letter of each word (initials/acronym)
>
>  (I still don't know which cipher is used)

Comment: [Sconibulus](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45034/30633) already offered this.

Comment: @Rubio Yep, you're right. I don't know how I missed that.