# Self-described Ciphers

Tags: cipher

This is a list of types of ciphers that are encrypted with their own ciphers.  If a given cipher requires a key, then the cipher is the key as well.  Also these are all actual ciphers, not methods to crack them like "frequency analysis".  It will require some brute-force, but they are all classically well-known ciphers and I believe most will be easy and some even trivial. This is posed as a challenge who can get them all first and also a good resource for newcomers wanting to learn some basic ciphers commonly used. Good luck!

> **1)** `EBG GUVEGRRA`
>   **2)** `#~%\cf`
>   **3)** `QQMIAIII`
>   **4)** `MGAARNA`
>   **5)** `LAYFPYRB`
>   **6)** `01100010 01101001 01101110 01100001 01110010 01111001 01110100     01101111 01110100 01100101 01111000 01110100`

Comment: "So feel free to comment a cipher that is self-encrypted and I will try to solve it and then add it." This is called "moving the goalposts": you shouldn't change the answer to a puzzle after it's posted.

Comment: (Also, I've downvoted because this seems to be low-effort. As you said, pretty much all of these are trivial, and this puzzle could easily be made by scanning through [Rumkin](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/) or [dcode.fr](https://www.dcode.fr/tools-list#cryptanalysis)'s lists and encrypting all of them. I would highly recommend not using solely ciphers if you want to make a high-quality puzzle - or not using ciphers *at all*, even.)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I thought it was worth the shot, but I see your point.

Comment: For what it's worth, [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45032/according-to-me)'s another puzzle that uses the same premise, but is more elaborate (and definitely was more challenging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ciphers are:

> 1. `ROT THIRTEEN`
>
>  2. `ROT-47`
>
>  3. `VIGENERE`
>
>  4. `ANAGRAM` (not a cipher...)
>
>  5. `PLAYFAIR`
>
>  6. `binarytotext`